# Application Error after a successful deployment at Heroku

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, heroku, deployment

I have a spring-boot project working fine in IntelliJ IDE, which I tried to deploy at Heroku server. The project was successfully deployed, but when I tried to access it from POSTMAN, I get the **503 error: the service is not available**.

Here the logging after a successful deployment from Heroku:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Java app detected
-----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
-----> Executing Maven
       $ ./mvnw -DskipTests clean dependency:list install
       [INFO] Scanning for projects...
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] ----------------< io.slcoder:authentication-server >-----------------
       [INFO] Building authentication-server 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
       [INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ authentication-server ---
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:list (default-cli) @ authentication-server ---
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ authentication-server ---
       [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
       [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
       [INFO] Copying 1 resource
       [INFO] Copying 1 resource
       [INFO] The encoding used to copy filtered properties files have not been set. This means that the same encoding will be used to copy filtered properties files as when copying other filtered resources. This might not be what you want! Run your build with --debug to see which files might be affected. Read more at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filtering-properties-files.html
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ authentication-server ---
       [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
       [INFO] Compiling 9 source files to /tmp/build_d09a68b1_/target/classes
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ authentication-server ---
       [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
       [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
       [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /tmp/build_d09a68b1_/src/test/resources
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ authentication-server ---
       [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
       [INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /tmp/build_d09a68b1_/target/test-classes
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ authentication-server ---
       [INFO] Tests are skipped.
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:3.3.1:war (default-war) @ authentication-server ---
       [INFO] Packaging webapp
       [INFO] Assembling webapp [authentication-server] in [/tmp/build_d09a68b1_/target/authentication-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
       [INFO] Processing war project
       [INFO] Building war: /tmp/build_d09a68b1_/target/authentication-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.1:repackage (repackage) @ authentication-server ---
       [INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ authentication-server ---
       [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_d09a68b1_/target/authentication-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war to /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/io/slcoder/authentication-server/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/authentication-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
       [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_d09a68b1_/pom.xml to /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/io/slcoder/authentication-server/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/authentication-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time:  8.024 s
       [INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-28T20:29:08Z
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 149.5M
```

Application log at Heroku:

```
2021-01-28T21:06:14.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user slcoder@gmail.com
2021-01-28T21:06:43.212587+00:00 app[api]: Release v12 created by user slcoder@gmail.com
2021-01-28T21:06:43.212587+00:00 app[api]: Deploy f113390b by user slcoder@gmail.com
2021-01-28T21:06:50.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-01-28T21:06:55.588865+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=authentication-server-app.herokuapp.com request_id=8710722d-c858-423a-bb8b-9268ef8318f3 fwd="196.74.101.204" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-28T21:06:59.516531+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=authentication-server-app.herokuapp.com request_id=0d6f4102-5dba-44b4-b717-d6d732d236bd fwd="196.74.101.204" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-29T00:17:50.789994+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=authentication-server-app.herokuapp.com request_id=fcba05fd-3c76-4830-af3e-dfc697b2f190 fwd="196.74.101.204" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-29T00:17:52.530644+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=authentication-server-app.herokuapp.com request_id=77736faf-0206-49dc-80be-3a1c0b5f061a fwd="196.74.101.204" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-29T11:20:59.963444+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=authentication-server-app.herokuapp.com request_id=c66098e0-1893-4d3f-90e3-e08f3afe0cea fwd="160.177.175.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-29T11:21:02.909523+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=authentication-server-app.herokuapp.com request_id=ee94b09c-f8c8-4783-a951-0c511007f93f fwd="160.177.175.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here is my POM.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.slcoder</groupId>
    <artifactId>authentication-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>authentication-server</name>
    <description>Server dedicated to authentication</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties** :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://zt9j9hwaktmzqprk:eayk987igm1t1shd@esilxl0nthgloe1y.chr7pe7iynqr.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/vqa34ov9ga2iumfm
spring.datasource.username=zt9j9hwaktmzqprk
spring.datasource.password=****************
spring.datasource.initialization-mode = always
spring.datasource.max-active=10
```

Could anyone help me out ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the output of your running application? `heroku logs`

Comment: I have just added it, it's the second snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, the core issue is that Heroku does not know how to run your application. You usually tell Heroku how to run your application with a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile).

However, since you're running Spring Boot, we will detect this and write out a Procfile for you. This did not happen here because you package your application as a WAR file which we cannot run as a standalone application.

If you change your Spring Boot packaging to JAR, Heroku should detect your app as a Spring boot app and you don't even need a Procfile. Try changing `<packaging>war</packaging>` to `<packaging>jar</packaging>` in your `pom.xml`.