# Heroku SprinBoot Deployment is sucess but Status is 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, heroku-cli

Hi I am trying to deploy a Spring Boot Application to Heroku. The build is a success but when I try to run the app I get a `Status 503: Service Unavailable` Error.

I referred a similar post
[Application Error after a successful deployment at Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65945017/application-error-after-a-successful-deployment-at-heroku)
but this didn't helped me.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.5.2
 

com.sample.app
sample-app
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
sample-app
Sample Project

<java.version>11</java.version>

jar


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.networknt</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.57</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is the error log from `heroku logs --tail`

```
Create a Procfile to customize the command used to run this process: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
2021-09-02T07:19:39.158915+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2021-09-02T07:19:39.162760+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UseContainerSupport -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2021-09-02T07:19:39.289159+00:00 app[web.1]: no main manifest attribute, in target/XXX.jar
2021-09-02T07:19:39.341327+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-09-02T07:19:39.636801+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-09-02T12:45:48.327297+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-09-02T12:45:52.218984+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -Dserver.port=28736 $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/XXX.jar`
2021-09-02T12:45:54.207103+00:00 app[web.1]: Create a Procfile to customize the command used to run this process: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
2021-09-02T12:45:54.250429+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2021-09-02T12:45:54.256963+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UseContainerSupport -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2021-09-02T12:45:54.426793+00:00 app[web.1]: no main manifest attribute, in target/XXX.jar
2021-09-02T12:45:54.485594+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-09-02T12:45:54.641187+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-09-02T15:51:38.369534+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=springboot-exp.herokuapp.com request_id=8c88bc1a-aae7-4c0e-9daa-b7ef602d2c47 fwd="71.69.151.195" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-09-02T15:51:38.626347+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=springboot-exp.herokuapp.com request_id=9e2333ec-26a8-46f5-b770-2565a59ef57d fwd="71.69.151.195" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-09-02T15:53:34.736916+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=springboot-exp.herokuapp.com request_id=0025da95-bb22-41b7-a085-63bf5664a7c5 fwd="71.69.151.195" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-09-02T15:53:34.885977+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=springboot-exp.herokuapp.com request_id=bbc9f8b4-a65f-4c95-9d2a-ce9d1b69ab02 fwd="71.69.151.195" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-09-02T15:53:54.458780+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=springboot-exp.herokuapp.com request_id=ceabd4ad-f5f3-4e35-b6e7-d0ca003df0b9 fwd="71.69.151.195" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-09-02T15:53:54.599062+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=springboot-exp.herokuapp.com request_id=463f5577-efbd-4d79-ad85-70462d20eaca fwd="71.69.151.195" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the failing logs mentions that a Procfile is needed for Heroku and a Spring Boot Application.

Taken from Spring Docs:
To customize Heroku builds, we need to provide a Procfile, which provides the incantation required to deploy an application. Heroku assigns a port for the Java application to use and then ensures that routing to the external URI works.

we must configure our application to listen on the correct port. Here’s the Procfile for a starter REST application:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem! The easiest solution for my case was to just use a Java 1.8 project - Heroku auto defaults to 1.8.

According to the Java Heroku docs [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#supported-java-versions), the supported version are as follows:

- Java 7 - `1.7.0_312`
- Java 8 - `1.8.0_302`
- Java 11 - `11.0.12`
- Java 13 - `13.0.8`
- Java 15 - `15.0.4`
- Java 16 - `16.0.2`

It seems you're using Java 11. To tell Heroku this, make a file called `system.properties` in your resources folder. In `system.properties`, add `java.runtime.version=11`. I believe you can also do `java.runtime.version=11.0.12`.

Hope this helps! Review the docs for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I already have a system.properties file. I am using open jdk 11. I did face some problem with version 11 but in that case the Heroku build would fail. I am pretty sure I have this error because I didn't had a Procfile. Still working to find the right solution.